# Calling Two Spring StoredProcedures Within One Transaction

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

We are changing the architecture of a legacy application to use Spring JDBC.

The application needs to call two stored procedures in a row within one transaction. Stored Procedure A registers a security token that is required to run stored procedure B:

```
BEGIN package_a.a('token'); END;
BEGIN package_b.b('foo','bar','baz'); END;
```

I've created Spring Stored Procedures for each of these:

```
@Component
public class SecurityTokenSP extends StoredProcedure {
    @Autowired
    public SecurityTokenSP(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds, "package_a.a");

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("token", Types.VARCHAR));

        compile();
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        Map<String, Object> inputParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inputParams.put("token", token);

        execute(inputParams);
    }
}

// Similar code for procedure B (FooBarBazSP)
```

I call both of these from a Service within one method:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityTokenSP securityTokenSP;
    @Autowired
    private FooBarBazSP fooBarBazSP;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void doIt(String foo, String bar, String baz) {
        securityTokenSP.setToken("myToken");
        fooBarBazSP.doIt(foo, bar, baz);
    }
}
```

Everything is wired correctly and each procedure is called. However the second procedure is acting as if the first procedure was not run. I suspect that Spring is calling 'commit' on the connection during the execute call, but that is just a theory.

I don't see how I can combine the two classes into one as the StoredProcedure constructor takes the name of a particular stored procedure and seems to be designed to just wrap one stored procedure.

Comment: Have you checked that your connection is not in auto-commit mode? Spring will not commit on its own with your config.

Comment: I'm using the same connection configuration that I've used on many Spring projects and have not done anything to explicitly turn on auto-commit.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the commit method of the connection or use p6spy to find out if the code really commits and this is the actual problem.

Comment: Please post your connection settings, just to have an eye on it.

Comment: Probably transaction is not setup properly. remove 2 lines and throw an exception to see the stack trace. you SHOULD see $Proxy in the stack trace.

Comment: I was using OracleDataSource which did not seem to respect setting autocommit(false). I've now switched to BasicDataSource and have not done anything in particular with setting autocommit, but it works.